# How to use visual components in delphi unit tests?

Tags: delphi, unit-testing, delphi-7, dunit

As is sometimes usual in visual applications, I have some code where data is maintained in a visual component (a TTreeView component). I'm refactoring the code and creating unit tests for the logic.

The only visual form in my test project is the GUITestRunner. In the future I plan to run the tests as a console application under a continuous integration server, so I won't have any form.

When I try to create a TTreeView widget without a parent and use it, I get the following  error:

```
Control '' has no parent window
```

What's the best way to create the widget on my test suite SetUp method and destroy it in the TearDown? Is it possible to use a visual widget in a console application? I don't need to display it, or even process events. I just have to create child nodes and access the data.

I managed to make it work with an ugly hack, but I'd like to know if there is some standard practice.

Sure, in my sunny and distant future, I'll refactor the code of this 21 thousand lines form, all my data will be in beautiful data structures and these kind of tests won't be necessary, but now I  need it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a hidden (i.e. non-visible) window to be the parent. Here is a sample console app that proves that this approach works.

```
program HiddenWindow;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Forms, StdCtrls;

var
  Form: TForm;

begin
  Form := TForm.Create(Application);
  with TListBox.Create(Form) do begin
    Parent := Form;
    Items.Add('test');//fails if the parent is not set
  end;
end.
```

Comment: +1 for a direct answer instead of whining about best practises and the difference between unit testing and GUI testing. ;)

Comment: Worked like a charm! It allowed me to turn on DUnit feature of failing a test when there's a memory leak. Now when I free the Form everything is deallocated. Now It will be easier to decouple the business logic from the interface. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In unit tests, you test the core functionality of a unit (which is rather a piece of logic than an actual literal unit-file). GUI is usually not part of this process.

You can however create an invisible form and place invisible controls on it. *[edit] See David's answer for a way to do that. [/edit]*
That way you may be able to test it. And you could use visual controls too. there are even test suites that can test visual controls by running some kind of prerecorded macro that fills in a form and pressed the right buttons.

But in fact this isn't the right way. GUI testing is different from Unit testing. The business logic should be seperated enough from your GUI to be able to test it alone, apart from the GUI and from other 'units'.

And 21 thousand lines isn't so much, is it? Got half a million lines here (alhough I wouldn't like needing to refactoring them either). :) Take it a step at a time. Refactor little pieces and write unit tests for each refactored piece. That way, you can keep your test for the future, because they *will* be usefull, even when all your code looks great and structured.

Comment: Your final two paragraphs contain the meat of this answer. Yes the business logic should be separated. In order to do that separation safely there needs to be a strong set of tests in place. Therefore testing that includes business logic coupled with GUI components is needed. My take is that this question is not about GUI testing but is about business logic testing where this unfortunate coupling with the GUI is present.

Comment: It is a tough decision to make. It would be very convenient to have unit tests available before refactoring code to check that your refactoring won't break it. But since the tests aren't here, you have to write them, and they will only test what you come up with now. It is very time consuming to write those test, and refactoring all this code means you'll have to refactor the tests as well. Therefor I doubt if it will pay off to write those tests now, instead of in the process of refactoring. If time and money are plenty, write them now. But they usually aren't. :)

Comment: Testing what you have now is generally what you want. It's the best way of discovering what your code is and what its spec is. Test cases are mostly an expression of spec. Writing the test cases after the refactoring is liable to lead to unintended regressions not being found. Note, all of the above assumes a large existing code base with users reliant on its current behaviour.

Comment: If you need an external service other than a mock or you are leaving "residue" somewhere in order to test, then you are doing integration testing, and *not* unit testing.

Comment: 500,000 lines in a single form? Wow! My life isn't so bad as I used to think.

Comment: Lol. I thought I meant in your whole application. :D No, per form I got at most a couple of hundreds of lines. The rest in in data models/business objects, although some of those could use some refactoring too. :)